# C++ what exactly does new <datatype>(<value>) do?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, new-operator, stack-memory

In this code:

```
int * p = new int(44);
```

p is allocated on the heap and the value it points to is 44;
but now I can also do something like this:

```
p[1] = 33;
```

without getting an error.  I always thought

```
int * p = new int(44);
```

was just another way of saying "P is allocated on the heap and points to an address containing 44" but apparently it makes p a pointer to an array of ints? is the size of this new array 44? Or is this result unusual.

Comment: `p[1]` is equivalent to `*(p + 1)`. You're (un)lucky it didn't crash. You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a) a good read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were right: P is allocated on the heap and points to an address containing 44.  There's no array allocated.  `p[1] = 33;` is what they call "undefined behavior".  Your program **might** crash, but it's not guaranteed to crash every single time you do this.

Comment: Close.  The variable "p" is allocated on the stack.  However, the memory it points to (44) is allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p_scalar = new int(5); //allocates an integer, set to 5.
```

If you access p_scalar[n] (n <> 0) it may crash

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the C++ language gives you a default implementation for the subscript operator for pointers that looks somehow similar to this:

```
(*Ptr)& operator[](size_t index)
{
   return *(address + index*sizeof(*Ptr));
}
```

This can always be overloaded and replaced for any type. Integers are not an exception, when you say:

```
int * pointer = alocate_int_array();
pointer[1] = 1;
```

You're using the compiler-augmented default implementation of that operator.